# Euler-Lagrange on restricted set

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I am reading a chapter of Evan's book on weak convergence methods for nonlinear PDE's p.49 and it states that the Euler Lagrange equation for the functional \begin{equation}
I[w]:=\int_U|Dw|^2
\end{equation}
(for some bounded, open domain, $U\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ for $n\ge 2$, with smooth boundary)
on the set $$\mathcal{A}:=\{w\in W^{1,2}(U,\mathbb{R^m}) : |w|=1 \text{ a.e. and  } w=g \text{ on } \partial U\}$$
is given by the solution to $$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=|Du|^2u  \\
|u|=1 \text{ a.e. }
\end{cases}
$$
in $U$.

My question is: how did they get this? I haven't really done much calculus of variations before but I think when you ignore that you are restricting the possible $w$'s the minimising function is just one with $\Delta u =0$ but I don't know how to use E-L for cases when the possible functions are restricted.

Also, is there a general way of dealing with these questions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove that $$\int_U Du:Dv=\int_U|Du|^2u\cdot v,\ \forall\ v\in W_0^{1,2}(U;\mathbb{R}^m)\cap L^\infty(U,\mathbb{R}^m)$$

Assume that $u\in\mathcal{A}$ is a critical point of $I$. Take $v\in W_0^{1,2}(U;\mathbb{R}^m)\cap L^\infty(U,\mathbb{R}^m)$ and note that for small $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that $u+tv\neq 0$ a.e. in $U$. Define $$u_t=\frac{u+tv}{|u+tv|}$$

I - Show that for small $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $u_t\in W^{1,2}(U,\mathbb{R}^m)$,

II - Compute $$\frac{d}{dt}I[u_t]_{t=0}$$

To conclude, note that $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}I[u_t]_{|t=0}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am still confused about how this answers my question! Please can you elaborate a little? You say that we want $u$ to be a harmonic mapping. Maybe I misunderstood - is this what it means for $u$ to satisfy $-\Delta u=|Du|^2u$ for $u\in \mathcal{A}$? If so then does then why consider the "Euler-Lagrange equation". Are we even using E-L? Finally, in your proof, what have you shown? I can not work out what you have shown other than a way to construct other critical points of $I$ given an element in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Ok, first I Have to know. Do you know what is a weak solution?

Comment: Yes I know that.

Comment: The meaning in this context for $u$ to satisfy the equation $-\Delta u=|Du|^2u$ in in the weak sense. So, when Evans say that the function $I$ is the energy function for the Euler equation above, he is saying that the critical points of $I$, must satisfy it in the weak sense. Now, if you do the second part of my answer, you will see that $$\frac{d}{dt}I[u_t]_{|t=0}=\int_U Du:Dv-\int |Du|^2u\cdot v$$

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense. Finally, what inspired you to consider the choice of $u_t$ above?

Comment: The idea is that $I$ is defined only for functions $u$ which saitsfies $|u|=1$ a.e. Now, think of $\mathcal{A}$ as a manifold, someting like a spehere. If you want to take some curve in the sphere that starts on some point $u$, then it is natural to sum to $u$ some term, let's say, $v$ and then normalize, i.e. $$\frac{u+v}{|u+v|}$$ PLease, if you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Oh OK, thanks! Sorry but one more question: Why do we need $v\in L^{\infty}$ as well as being in the usual $W^{1,2}$?

Comment: We have to ask $v\in L^\infty$, because of term $|Du|^2$ in the multiplication $|Du|^2 u\cdot v$. Note that the term $|Du|^2$ only belongs to $L^1(U)$. If you that $v$ only belogs to $W^{1,2}$, you have that $u\cdot v$ only belongs to $L^1$ and then, $|Du|^2 u\cdot v$ does not need to be integrable.

Comment: You are welcome